# Can't find button element by descriptor 'dojoValidateValid_focus TextBox_TwoCells_width TextBox_focus" style='

Tags: linux, testrigor

Recently, I registered with Testrigor and am using its Free version. We need to test dynamic web applications in testrigor, then we write scripts for the same. I am getting the following error in one field (location/address). Please check attached screenshot. Please help me resolve the problem.
Can't find button element by descriptor 'dojoValidateValid_focus TextBox_TwoCells_width  TextBox_focus" style='
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrROI.png)

Name,Class Referanced are used for error field

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After verifying the test steps, we checked that the input "1st Line" is being clicked, so instead of `enter "Parekh Integrated services Pvt Ltd," into "1st line"`
After that the click, you can use:

`enter "Parekh Integrated services Pvt Ltd,"`

or

`type "Parekh Integrated services Pvt Ltd,"`